# Качество шифрования для накапливаемых переменных в приложении

Tags: android, c++, шифрование, библиотеки

Есть игрушка на android. Играя в нее, игрок зарабатывает монетки, на которые он может апгрейдить себя в перерывах между раундами. Задача в том, что нужно хранить количество этих монет на диске (в файлике), но так, чтобы их нельзя было просто так изменить вручную, не игровыми средствами (вполне возможно, что к этим монеткам будет привязана монетизация игры).

Вопрос в чем: как я понимаю, лучше всего такие данные как-то обратимо зашифровать. Какой алгоритм шифрования лучше всего подойдет для подобной цели и какая библиотека его реализует, Очень желательно, чтобы она представляла собой набор фалов исходного кода, которые просто добавляются в проект и не тянула лишнего функционала (грубо говоря две функции, одна шифрует, вторая дешифрует). Язык - С++.

Или может быть я иду вообще в неправильном направлении и подобное реализуется как-то абсолютно иначе.

Comment: В крайнем случае можно своё шифрование написать. Благо, речь не о валютных операций международного уровня. Для того, чтобы расшифровать самописное было не так просто, стоит добавлять случайные символы (лучше и на псевдослучайные места) и делать так, чтобы увеличение количество монет на 1 единицу не приводило к изменению лишь одного символа в зашифрованной строке.

Comment: По мне, всю монетизацию нужно хранить на сервере, и весь purchase/award с ним синхронизировать. Шифрование тоже нужно, чтобы просто так артмани не проехались и не подправили себе няшек, но приоритет должен быть на авторизации монетизации с серверной стороны. "Клиент всегда врет" - есть такое правило для работы клиент-серверных приложений, и все данные от клиента нужно на сервере проверять.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё очень просто. Вам нужно вязть любой алгоритм шифрования и добавить в свой проект. Если не хочется возиться с библиотеками, то проще всего найти реализацию AES и добавить к себе в проект. Реализаций в интернете полно. Вот [к примеру](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1380/A-C-Implementation-of-the-Rijndael-Encryption-Decr), одна из них. Ключ шифрования храните в [keychain](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyChain.html)(я совершенно не знаком с andorid, но это выглядит и называется как то, что нужно).

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно не шифрование, а [контрольная сумма](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0). Потому как задача не в том чтобы скрывать данные, а чтобы контролировать их целостность. Используйте хоть тот же [MD5](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) и [солите](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F)) данные. Хэш храните/дублируйте в надежном месте, например, как вам подсказывают, на сервере.

Свое шифрование придумывать не надо - это отдельная очень сложная работа.